# What is the difference between the two types of red Aloe Vera?

Tags: identification, succulents, aloe

What is the difference between these two red aloe veras? And what’s unique about them?[image: Green skin] [image: Red skin]

Answer (score 1):

The second picture is Aloe cameronii - its gets redder in sun, but new leaves usually start out green. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aloe_cameronii

The cut aloe in the first picture is not possible to identify because the whole plant is not visible,though it is clearly a different variety from the second plant. The red gel inside might be a feature of the plant, or it might mean the leaf section is not fresh, and bacteria has invaded the gel. There are over 500 varieties of Aloe, but Aloe vera is usually the one juice is extracted from. Juices from Aloe vera are sometimes pink/red, other times clear, and it seems no one's quite sure why, see here https://aloe1.com/pink-aloe/